# Creating RadioButtons programmatically

Tags: android, radio-button

I want to create a series of radio buttons which correspond to an array of strings within an Android app.  The radio buttons should toggle content to be displayed from the array.  How do I do this?

Comment: Have you done something so far. Show us your progress, so we can help you

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You must add the radio buttons to a [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) and then the `RadioGroup` to the `layout`

I miss some information like what is submit, but your code should look like:

```
private void createRadioButton() {
    final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[5];
    RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this); //create the RadioGroup
    rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);//or RadioGroup.VERTICAL
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        rb[i]  = new RadioButton(this);
        rg.addView(rb[i]); //the RadioButtons are added to the radioGroup instead of the layout
        rb[i].setText("Test");
    }
    ll.addView(rg);//you add the whole RadioGroup to the layout
    ll.addView(submit); 
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
                rg.removeView(rb[i]);//now the RadioButtons are in the RadioGroup
            }  
            ll.removeView(submit);
            Questions();
        }
    });   
}
```

Another code for dynamically creating the `radiobutton`

```
<TableRow>
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/radiobuttons">
     </RadioGroup>
</TableRow>
```

Code:

```
public void makeRadioButtons(Vector tmpVector, int i, LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp)
{
     RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);
     rb.setText((String) tmpVector.elementAt(i));
     //rg is private member of class which refers to the radio group which I find
     //by id.
     rg.addView(rb, 0, lp);

}
```

Comment: what is **ll** in **ll.removeView(submit);**?

Comment: @partho I would guess it represents a `LinearLayout` instance?