# "Checking one radio button unchecks all the others" doesn't work

Tags: java, android, radio-group

I'm developing an Android 3.1 tablet application and I need to create some Radio buttons programmatically:

```
    RadioGroup radGrp = new RadioGroup(mActivity);
    params.weight = 0.2f;
    radGrp.setLayoutParams(params);
    radGrp.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);

    String tag = Long.toString(req.getRequirementId()) + "_" +
            getString(R.string.yes);
    RadioButton radioBtnYES = new RadioButton(mActivity);
    radioBtnYES.setText(getString(R.string.yes));
    radioBtnYES.setTag(tag);
    radioBtnYES.setChecked(confValue);
    radioBtnYES.setOnClickListener(radioListener);
    radGrp.addView(radioBtnYES);

    tag = Long.toString(req.getRequirementId()) + "_" +
            getString(R.string.no);
    RadioButton radioBtnNO = new RadioButton(mActivity);
    radioBtnNO.setText(getString(R.string.no));
    radioBtnNO.setTag(tag);
    radioBtnNO.setChecked(!confValue);
    radioBtnNO.setOnClickListener(radioListener);
    radGrp.addView(radioBtnNO);

    radGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedChangedListener);
    requirementLayout.addView(radGrp);
```

My problem is that when I tap on an unchecked radio button the other one on the same Radio Group it is still checked.

This is `radioListener` code:

```
private RadioButton.OnClickListener radioListener = 
        new RadioButton.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        String tag = v.getTag().toString();
        String[] parts = tag.split("_");

        if ((parts != null) && (parts.length == 2))
        {
            boolean value = (parts[1].equals(getString(R.string.yes)));

            Long id = Long.valueOf(parts[0]);
            requirementsState.put(id, value);
        }
    }
};
```

And this is `checkedChangedListener` code:

```
private RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener checkedChangedListener =
        new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
            {
                RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)
                        mActivity.findViewById(checkedId);

                group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

                group.clearCheck();
                rb.setChecked(true);

                group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedChangedListener);
            }
};
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: try using onCheckChangelistener to check other radiobutton in radiogroup

Comment: have you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646442/set-radiobutton-programmatically-android

Comment: I have updated my question with more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer: **I need to setup checked radio button after add all radio butons to radio group.

This is my working code:

```
    RadioGroup radGrp = new RadioGroup(mActivity);
    params.weight = 0.2f;
    radGrp.setLayoutParams(params);
    radGrp.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);

    String tag = Long.toString(req.getRequirementId()) + "_" +
            getString(R.string.yes);
    RadioButton radioBtnYES = new RadioButton(mActivity);
    radioBtnYES.setText(getString(R.string.yes));
    radioBtnYES.setTag(tag);
    radioBtnYES.setOnClickListener(radioListener);
    radGrp.addView(radioBtnYES);

    tag = Long.toString(req.getRequirementId()) + "_" +
            getString(R.string.no);
    RadioButton radioBtnNO = new RadioButton(mActivity);
    radioBtnNO.setText(getString(R.string.no));
    radioBtnNO.setTag(tag);
    radioBtnNO.setOnClickListener(radioListener);
    radGrp.addView(radioBtnNO);
```

I've added two Radio Buttons to Radio Group and then:

```
    if (confValue)
        radioBtnYES.setChecked(true);
    else
        radioBtnNO.setChecked(true);

    requirementLayout.addView(radGrp);
```