# Cast exception when adding RadioButtons to RadioGroup in Android

Tags: android

I need to dynamically add RadioButtons to the app, and when I add either buttons or group to the layout it works perfectly. But when I try to add RadioButtons to RadioGroup app crashes with cast exception: *android.widget.RadioButton cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout*

I've used this post for reference: 
[Creating RadioButtons programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646442/creating-radiobuttons-programmatically).
It must be something really basic, but I've been playing with it for a while now, so a bit overwhelmed trying to solve it.

Here is my code:

```
protected void addRadioButtons(LinearLayout layout, String switchOptions){  
    String[] optionsArray = switchOptions.split(",");
    int numberOfOptions = optionsArray.length;
    RadioButton[] radioButton = new RadioButton[numberOfOptions];
    RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);
    radioGroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
    LayoutParams radioGroupParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    radioGroup.setLayoutParams(radioGroupParams);
    //layout.addView(radioGroup);

    for (int i = 0; i<numberOfOptions;i++){
        radioButton[i] = new RadioButton(this);
        radioButton[i].setText(i + "");
        radioGroup.addView(radioButton[i]);
    }
    layout.addView(radioGroup);
   }
```

Comment: the exception is pointing to this line: `radioGroup.addView(radioButton[i]);`??

Comment: `radioGroup.addView(radioButton[i],i,radioGroupParams )`  try this

Comment: It didn't work. Exception points to the method call, but when I comment this line out or replace radioGroup with layout everything works. Well apart from the fact that all Radio buttons can be selected.

Comment: what happens when you try the above mentioned in the comment

Comment: Exactly the same exception

Comment: This doesn't make sense. I have code that's very similar and it works fine. i looked up `ViewGroup`'s `addView(view)` and it indeed is expecting a `view`, not a `LinearLayout`. Have you CLEANed your project lately?  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View%29

Comment: Yeah, just cleaned everything now. Still the same story. =(

Comment: Well, we know that `addView()` takes a `View`...so something else is wrong here. to simplify, could you perhaps comment out the `for` loop and just add a simple `RadioButton`?

Comment: @etilia post the stack trace this will help us pin point the error

Comment: Commented out the whole loop and added a single simple RadioButton:'RadioButton choice = new RadioButton(this);
     choice.setText("test");
     //layout.addView(choice);
     radioGroup.addView(choice);'
Crashes on radioGroup(not commented out) and adds nicely on layout.

Comment: Huh? `Crashes`..., but `...adds nicely on layout.`? Which?

Comment: when I replace radioGroup.addView(choice); with layout.addView(choice); layout - the one, which is passed as parameter, it works fine. Must be something else.

Comment: Thinking back to my code (don't have it in front of me now), i believe that i added the `RadioGroup` to the layout prior to adding any `RadioButton`s to the `RadioGroup`. might give that a try (i see you have tried that at some point `//layout.addView(radioGroup);`)

Comment: Yeah, I've tired that. I've just deleted another one of the elements above RadioGroup on this form and it works now. Must be a problem with that, weird, they are not linked at all :-/

Comment: well, the Exception was clearly incorrect. Way to go...and good luck going forward.